# Controlling Metadata Search Refiners in Search Refinement Panel

Tags: search, managed-metadata, publishing, search-results

I'm trying to figure out why not all of my Metadata terms appear as refiners in the Refinement Panel.

I have the following content type structure:

- Lawyer
- Office
- News

There are Metadata terms for:

- Lawyer
- Office

The content types are related to each other via Metadata columns:

- Lawyer has an Office
- News is related to Lawyers
- News is related to Offices

When I perform a search, Related Offices always appears in the Refinement Panel, allowing me to filter results by Office.

However, none of the other Metadata columns appear as refiners.  For example, I expect that would be able to also filter by Lawyer when I have News items in the search results.

I ran a full search crawl.

I also started experimenting with the Filter Category Definition property of the Refinement Panel, specifically the MetadataThreshold property (setting it to 0), but that hasn't made a difference.

```
<Category    
   Title="Managed Metadata Columns"    
   Description="Managed metadata of the documents"  
   Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"      
   MetadataThreshold="0"
   NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"
   MaxNumberOfFilters="20"
   ShowMoreLink="True"
   MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"
   MoreLinkText="show more"    
   LessLinkText="show fewer" />
```

Appreciate the help!

EDIT: Wanted to add that I'm provisioning the metadata columns according to [this blog post](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/09/adding-managed-metadata-fields-to-sharepoint-publishing-pages/) by Ari Bakker.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

Are those columns site columns? Have you performed a full crawl? 
This [site](http://www.avanadeblog.com/sharepointasg/2011/12/custom-search-refinements-based-on-content-type-fields.html) may help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you set the **Number of Categories to Display** found on the Refinement tab in the web part properties of the Refinement Panel to a higher number than 6?

Comment: Would make a better comments than a answer.